# How to sort dataframe in numerical ascending order?

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, dataframe

I'm having my Dataframe which contains two columns. I want to sort this Dataframe in numerical ascending order. I'm tried to sort it but It will sort in the alphabetical order which I don't want.

I'm tried with following code :

**program code-**

```
dfs.sort_index(ascending=True,inplace=True)
```

I refer this link for duplication of question :
[this_link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33314175/numerical-sort-a-column-containing-numbers-and-strings-pandas-python)

But when I'm printing my dataframe my column 0 is value. But I want to sort by using this keys like 1021,3,4,5 ect of 1st index.

```
           0
0 1021    00
  3       88
  4       18
  5       IB
  8     7.75
  854      n
  9      829

           0
0 1021    00
  3       88
  4       18
  5       IB
  8     7.75
  854      n
  9      829
```

**DataFrame :**

```
1021    1500
1584   88929
3       1388
388   157.75
394   157.75
4       1388
444      n/a
474   157.75
5        IBM
8     157.75
854        n
9      88929
```

**Expected Output-**

```
3       1388
4       1388
5        I
8     157.75
9      88929
388   157.75
394   157.75
444      n/a
474   157.75
854        n
1021    1500
1584   88929
```

Is there any way to sort Dataframe like this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [numerical sort a column containing numbers and strings (pandas/python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33314175/numerical-sort-a-column-containing-numbers-and-strings-pandas-python)

Comment: That doesn't look like a dataframe (no column headers)?

Comment: @ayhan- No. I removed column headers. I don't want this in the output.

Comment: @Selcuk- What should I put in the sort() of which column? see my edit. keys are not specifying any column value.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the values are numeric by forcing it explicit `a = a[:,0].astype(int)`. Then try `a[a[:, 0].argsort()]`, where `a` is the dataframe and `0` is the column index. 
More on syntax - http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html

Comment: see my question. my column index 0 is value and I want to sort by these keys.