# Why is my df.sort_values() not correctly sorting the data points?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with returns from various investments in %. sort.values does not correctly order my returns. For example I just want to simply see the TEST column returns sorted by lowest to highest or vice versa. Please look at the test output, it is not correct.

`df.sort_values('TEST')`

gives me an output of returns that are NOT sorted correctly. [Sort values code not in correct order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJz8v.jpg)

Also I am having an issue where it sorts positive numbers lowest to highest, then half way down starts again for negative numbers lowest to highest.

I just want it to look like following:
-3%
-1%
-0.5%
1%
2%
5%

Comment: looks like you are sorting strings  lexicographically,  check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33314175/numerical-sort-a-column-containing-numbers-and-strings-pandas-python

Answer (score 0):

Go for [`numpy.lexsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html) and [*boolean indexing*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) :

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([float(x.rstrip("%")) for x in df["TEST"]])
idx = np.lexsort((arr,))
​
df = df.iloc[idx]
​
```

Output :

```
print(df)
​
    TEST
0    -3%
1    -1%
2  -0.5%
3     1%
4     2%
5     5%
```

*Input used :*

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"TEST": ["1%", "-3%","-0.5%", "-1%", "5%", "2%"]})

    TEST
0     1%
1    -3%
2  -0.5%
3    -1%
4     5%
5     2%
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the lexicographic order of string is different from the natural order (1->10->2 vs 1->2->10).

One option using the `key` parameter of `sort_values`:

```
df.sort_values('TEST', key=lambda s: pd.to_numeric(s.str.extract(r'(-?\d+\.?\d*)', expand=False)))
```

Or:

```
df.sort_values('TEST', key=lambda s: pd.to_numeric(s.str.rstrip('%')))
```

Output:

```
    TEST
1    -3%
3    -1%
2  -0.5%
0     1%
5     2%
4     5%
```

Comment: Hi your first solution works - thank you. TEST was just one column. Let's say I now have a big data set with 100 columns and I want to apply this same logic, is there a way to do this without listing each column indiidually. I.E Can I somehow convert the whole CSV to have this formatting? Thank you

Comment: @JoeBloggs90 can you provide an extra input/output example with more columns? Are all columns to be sorted with the same logic?